# How to guarantee file creation no matter where the application is hosted

Tags: c#, file

I'm working on a C# application that will be hosted somewhere I'm not aware about the server details  .

In this application , I will generate a temporary file and transfer it to an MFT server than delete the temp file after the transfer, which means I'm not worried about space issues .

Which of the method below , could guarantee the temp file creation no matter what :

```
var systemPath = System.Environment.
                             GetFolderPath(
                                 Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
                             );
var complete = Path.Combine(systemPath , "file");
```

Or simply [File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.file.create(v=vs.110).aspx) could do the job :

```
File.Create("fileName");
```

I'm aware that I can introduce exceptions handling , but the idea is that the file "must" be created no matter where and no matter what because it's just a temp file that will be deleted after

Comment: You can use [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) - _"Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file."_

Comment: [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr‌ary/system.io.path.g‌​ettempfilename(v=vs.‌​110).aspx)

Comment: @stuartd does `Path.GetTempFileName() ` allows temp files creation on servers even if the application is a Desktop based and not web based ?If yes feel free to mark it as an answer because it's exactly what I was looking for and thanks

Comment: If you're running your desktop app **on** the server while logged-in as a user then yes I can guarantee it will work. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @stuartd Yes , exactly ok thank you , feel free to mark it as an answer so we can close it

Comment: Just a caveat - _"I can guarantee it will work"_ - as long as the current user has permissions to write to the temp folder, which would be true by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

> Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file.